# Migrate provider from hibernate to eclipselink and get OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipselink, persistence

I change my persistence.xml to use eclipselink provider. Now I'm getting OutOfMemoryError when application starts...

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<!--        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> -->
        <properties>
<!--            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class,hbm" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" /> -->
<!--            <property name="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="CALL_CENTER" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" /> -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger" />
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Eclipselink from consuming all memory with the cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914887/how-can-i-prevent-eclipselink-from-consuming-all-memory-with-the-cache)

Comment: You turned off caching, so you'll have to use profiling to see what is eating up your memory.